# try catch, not catching fetch() 502 gateway exception

Tags: javascript, post, error-handling, request, fetch

For some reason, whenever there is an invalid URL that causes a 502 exception, the code throws an error in the console and breaks. Ignoring the try {} catch{}

```
  async function getHeight(url) {
    const serviceUrl = url
    try {
      const request = fetch(Proxy+"http://"+url+"/v1/query/height", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      });

      return [serviceUrl, request]
    }
    catch {
      return [serviceUrl, "failed"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this before and it appears the browser errors it out. But you should be able to catch it. Try it this way.

```
try {

} catch(error) {
  if (!error.response){
    return [serviceUrl, "No server response."]
  } else if (error.response.status === 502) {
    return [serviceUrl, "Bad gateway"]
  } else { [serviceUrl, "Server unable to process request."] }
}
```